Shade tikz intersection
I'm currently trying to shade a region of the Argand diagram for the solutions of an exam I am writing.  I have managed to draw the shape below, but I am lost as to how to shade the yellow region.

My MWE is below; I have tried to use the odd even rule and non zero rule, but have become hopelessly lost!
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0) circle [radius=2];
    \draw (-1,0) circle [radius=1];
    \draw (-1,0) circle [radius=0.6mm];
    \draw[dashed] (180:1) -- (45:3);
    \draw[dashed] (180:1) -- (120:3);
    \draw[thick,-latex](-4,0) -- node[at end,below]{Re}(2,0);
    \draw[thick,-latex](0,-3) -- node[at end,below left]{Im}(0,3);
    \node[below] at (-1,0){$-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

I would welcome some suggestions!

There are lots of ways to go about doing this. spath3 comes to mind, as does the intersections library. I like this way for basic cases because it's more simple. Remember to put things in the foreground last, and things in the background first.
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (-1,0) circle [radius=2];
        \fill[yellow] (45:3) -- (180:1) -- (120:3);
        \fill[white] (180:1) circle[radius=1];
    \end{scope}
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0) circle [radius=2];
    \draw (-1,0) circle [radius=1];
    \draw (-1,0) circle [radius=0.6mm];
    \draw[dashed] (180:1) -- (45:3);
    \draw[dashed] (180:1) -- (120:3);
    \draw[thick,-latex](-4,0) -- node[at end,below]{Re}(2,0);
    \draw[thick,-latex](0,-3) -- node[at end,below left]{Im}(0,3);
    \node[below] at (-1,0){$-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


